# grabbing only certain array inside array

Tags: php, arrays

Basically, I'm receiving an `array()` from the **Yahoo Messenger API in PHP** and am in the process of developing an **notification system**, It returns an array with both the **IM** received from an chat and my contacts.

```
Array (
[0] => Array 
    (
        [message] => Array
            (
                [status] => 1
                [sequence] => 0
                [sender] => SenderCurtis
                [receiver] => receiverCurtis
                [msg] => #1
                [timeStamp] => 1374187598
                [hash] => y2qlDf8uTq8tXzgzrsSMyjQB+W2uDg==
                [msgContext] => y2qlDf8uTq8tXzgzrsSMyjQB+W2uDg==
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [buddyInfo] => Array
            (
                [sequence] => 1
                [contact] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [sender] => SenderCurtis
                                [presenceState] => 0
                                [avatarUser] => 0
                                [avatarPreference] => 0
                                [clientCapabilities] => 8915971
                                [clientUserGUID] => MI7STHUYOAMCGE5TNTY7CJPFWM
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [message] => Array
            (
                [status] => 1
                [sequence] => 2
                [sender] => SenderCurtis
                [receiver] => receiverCurtis
                [msg] => #2
                [timeStamp] => 1374187601
                [hash] => 3+2s9sIvjPRdvneQsMgVNCKBTFgKwQ==
                [msgContext] => 3+2s9sIvjPRdvneQsMgVNCKBTFgKwQ==
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [buddyInfo] => Array
            (
                [sequence] => 3
                [contact] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [sender] => myContactUser1@yahoo.com
                                [presenceState] => 0
                                [avatarUser] => 0
                                [avatarPreference] => 0
                                [clientCapabilities] => 8915971
                                [clientUserGUID] => UQU3WV7ZOZ2OTGLJQUE2QJU4ZU
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

How can I grab just the **message** `array()` and iterate through it? such as "Message 1", "Message2" etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to filter the array values for the key 'message', you could do something like this in PHP:

```
$messages = array();

foreach ($response as $key => $data) {
    if (array_key_exists('message', $data)) {
        $msgArray = $data['message'];
        $messages[] = $msgArray;
    }
}
```

In the above sample, I'm storing the messages in their own array. But you could process the data right inside the for-loop too, if you want that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `array_map()` is the function you are looking for here. The `array_map` function allows you to execute a callback on each element of an existing array and assemble a new array consisting only of the values returned by the callback.

What you would want to do is something like this :

```
$data = // lets assume this is the data you received
$messages_data = array_map( "extract_message", $data );

function extract_message( $data_item ){
  if ( array_key_exists( 'message', $data_item ) ){
    return $data_item[ 'message' ];
  }
}
```

Now your `$message_data` array will contain only the message arrays from the original array.

Comment: OK, that's a cleaner solution ;) But you'll probably want to check if the key 'message' exists, in stead of getting undefined index warnings :)

Comment: `array_filter` would suit better I think, because the key `message` doesn't exists for every entry.

Comment: -1 you haven't tested it right? should be `array_map('extract_message', $data)` + you get empty keys

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($var[0] as $key => $value)
{
    do things with each message
}
```

where `$var` is substituted for your actual variable name

Answer (score 0):

Just filter your array using [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
  $messages = array_filter($data, function($a){ return isset($a["message"]); });
```

Then use [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get rid of the unwanted intermediate array.

```
  $messages = array_map(function($a){ return $a["message"]; }, $message);
```

then you can iterate over it with a foreach or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Because I like SPL iterators here another solution. Works with PHP >= 5.1.0.

```
class MessageIterator extends FilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
        return array_key_exists('message', $this->getInnerIterator()->current());
    }

    public function current()
    {
        $current = parent::current();
        return $current['message'];
    }
}

$iterator = new MessageIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));

foreach ($iterator as $message) {
    print_r($message);
}
```

Comment: I like iterators, but the SPL ones are kinda crap. I wish people would start upping to 5.5 so I can finally start using generators.